# Frequency table of lists within multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

I have some (a lot) binary encoded vectors like:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] #But with many more elements each one
```

and they are all stored into a numpy (2D) array like:

```
[
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
]
```

I want to get a **frequency table of each label set**. So, in this example, the frequency table will be:

```
[2,1]
```

Because the 1st label set has two appearances and the 2nd label set just one.

In other words, I want to implement [itemfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html) from Scipy or [histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) from numpy, but not for single elements but for lists.

Now I have the following code implemented:

```
def get_label_set_freq_table(labels):
    uniques = np.empty_like(labels)
    freq_table = np.zeros(shape=labels.shape[0])
    equal = False

    for idx,row in enumerate(labels):
        for lbl_idx,label_set in enumerate(uniques):
            if np.array_equal(row,label_set):
                equal = True
                freq_table[lbl_idx] += 1
                break
        if not equal:
            uniques[idx] = row
            freq_table[idx] += 1
        equal = False

    return freq_table
```

being *labels* the binary encoded vectors.

It works well, but it's extremly low when the number of vectors is big (>58.000) and the number of elements in each one is also big (>8.000)

**How can this be done in a more efficient way?**

Comment: That doesn't look one-hot to me.

Comment: You are right, I'll edit the question to "binary" vectors. Thanks. Also @Divakar is right with the same appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you meant an array with 1s and 0s only. For those, we can reduce each row to a scalar with *binary scaling* and then use `np.unique` -

```
In [52]: a
Out[52]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

In [53]: s = 2**np.arange(a.shape[1])

In [54]: a1D = a.dot(s)

In [55]: _, start, count = np.unique(a1D, return_index=1, return_counts=1)

In [56]: a[start]
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])

In [57]: count
Out[57]: array([2, 1])
```

Here's a generalized one -

```
In [33]: unq_rows, freq = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=1)

In [34]: unq_rows
Out[34]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

In [35]: freq
Out[35]: array([1, 2])
```

Comment: I forgot about the axis parameter...
Wow! Your solution is great! So efficient and so elegant! Thank you very much! Checked and works like a charm, accepted answer!